# How can I display the folders that require root acess in android?

Tags: android, root, android-file, cyanogenmod

I am working on a android app and i want the user to be able to view the folders that require root access. I tried looking through the Cyanogenmod file manager code to try and trying the su command in java with the Runtime thing, but I had no luck.

Comment: maybe "adb shell" can help you

Comment: I want to be able to do it within the app.. Can you run adb shell commands directly from apps?

Comment: it seems it's not possible:(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without rooting the device (which simply means gaining required root access level). That's basically the reason for permission system - to keep you away from the places you should not be looking in.